# Product of Lebesgue-null-set and arbitrary Lesbesgue-set is a Lebesgue-null-set again

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I already know that for Borel-$\sigma$-algebras it holds that $\mathfrak B^{p+q}=\mathfrak B^p \otimes\mathfrak B^q$. Now I want to show that this is not the case for Lebesgue-$\sigma$-algebras $\mathfrak L$.

So first of all, given a zero Lebesgue-null-set $N$ in $\mathbb R^p$, how can I show that $N\times B$ is a Lebesgue-null-set in $\mathbb R^{p+q}$ for arbitrary $B\subseteq \mathbb R^q$?

**My work:**
So if we chose $B$ where $\mu(B)<\infty$, isn't it obvious that we obtain $$\lambda(N\times B)=\nu(N)\mu(B)=0\times M=0$$ where $M\in\mathbb R$ is an upper bound of $\mu(B)$?

Thus I considered the case $\mu(B)>\infty$. Since $\mu$ is $\sigma$ -additive, we can find a sequence $B_n\subseteq B$ such that $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_n = B$ and $\mu(B_n)<\infty$ for all $n$.
It follows that $$\lambda(N\times B)= \lambda(N\times \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_n )=\nu(N)\mu(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_n) = \nu(N)\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu( B_n)=0\times S=0$$ where $S$ is the upper bound of $B_n$.

Is that right?

Comment: What you mean under $\mu(B)>\infty$? It seems you must take any $B$ with $\mu(B)=\infty$.   Your proof is correct-this follows also from Fubini theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You  can take  a set  $N \times  X_0$ where $N$ is Lebesgue measurable subset in $R^p$ with $\nu(N)=0$ and  $X_0  \subseteq R^q$ is not Lebesgue measurable, i.e., $X_0 \notin L(R^q)$. Then set $N \times  X_0$ has $\lambda$ measure zero because  $\lambda$ is complete measure and $\lambda(N \times R^q)=0$. This set stands an example of a set which belongs to  $L(R^p\times R^q)$ but no to the sigma algebra  $L(R^p) \times L(R^q)$.